# Find most recent date in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need some help with the code below. What I'm trying to do is activate the cell with the latest date in column "A". When I try to activate the cell it keeps activating cell "OIY3", and there's no values in those columns.

```
sub test

Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))

MsgBox CDate(Max_date)

Cells(Max_date).Activate

End sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a typical method:

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    Max_date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("A"))
    MsgBox CDate(Max_date)
    Set r = Range("A:A").Find(What:=CDate(Max_date), After:=Range("A1"))
    r.Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set `Max_date` to the value, not to the cell address. So Excel is trying to interpret a date as a cell address.

[This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24286226/how-to-get-the-cell-address-of-max-in-vba) should provide you with the answer you want.